# Visual Studio Code Document Selector missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I  lost document selector, where i can quickly switch between open documents. Maybe it is some simple settings, i can find where to enable it.

[image: visual studio code missing tabs]

See i have multiple open documents, but only one tab showing on top of edior window.

Any idea how to get it all open document tabs show up ?

Comment: Did you change this setting:   "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,

Comment: Thanks, i enabled workbench.editor.showTabs in settings. I never used settings before. I had to find it now.  This happend while i was working (usual edits, nothing to do with editor or its settings), not sure if i press some key that caused this. Anyway it is back now.